# Android NullPointerException - Debugging a specific line

Tags: java, android, debugging, nullpointerexception

If I have a line like this:

```
var.getSomething().getSomethingElse().setNewValue(stuff.getValue().getWhatever());
```

If that line creates a `NullPointerException`, is there any way of finding out which method is returning a **null** value?

I believe I was able to split the line at every dot and get the exception showing which line was failing. But I can't get that to work anymore (maybe I remember incorrectly).

Is the only good debugging possibility to write it like this?

```
a = var.getSomething();
b = a.getSomehingElse();
c = stuff.getValue();
d = c.getWhatever();
b.setNewValue(d);
```

With this I should be able to easily see where the exception happens. But it feels inefficient and ugly to write this way.

I use Android Studio. Used Eclipse before but moved to Android Studio some time ago.

Comment: Why don't use debugger to estimate the value of each call?

Comment: In eclipse you can select a specific part in Debug-Mode than right click "inspect" and you get the return value from this part.

Comment: I believe logcat show where exactly NPE occur. (IMO) You have to follow the log.

Comment: I should probably read up on using debugging tools better.

I use android-studio and most of these exceptions are hard do reproduce. Often the users manage to get these exceptions in some strange ways. So it may be hard to debug on my hardware.

Nope, I've only seen logcat display anything else than the line numbers.

Comment: in android studio just run in debug mode with same running configuration and when you come to this line there is every value in line written. Also you can go right click and evaluate expression which is selected by mouse. Quiet straightforward.

Comment: just write each method in separate line like this: https://codeshare.io/Yc6ZF

Comment: @pskink Does it matter if i put new lines before or after the dots? I've tried the latter option but it doesn't seem to be working in the current version of Android Studio anyway. Though I think I might have had it working before.

Comment: did you try that? what line number do you see in your  `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @pskink It pointed to the first line with the variable ("var."). Which should be possible to have as null without any problem. The exception should happen when trying to run a method of a null value ("var.getValue()").

Comment: so `var` is null, isn't it?

Comment: @pskink It couldn't be as I display data from it in another location. It would be really strange if that was the case. But I'll try to investigate it some more.

Comment: @JimmyGarpehäll if you don't know easy way to reproduce NPE it is better to make you code more robust with Nullable, NonNull annotations, as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @rude Thanks It's a nice idea and I will look into it. Though I'm creating the objects from json-data from a server and it might return null values sometimes depending on what you request. I try to check the content before using the data/objects but in some cases, like this one, the object is null for some strange reason when it, in my mind, shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to put every part into "Watches":

[image]

But I'm pretty sure that both Eclipse and Android Studio would let you inspect the content by just a selection of the part you' re interested in (if you are in debug mode)

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest to a solution. I managed to reproduce the exception and then this helped. The problem was getting to know how to reproduce the error. And to get that it seems I have to split my line into multiple shorter ones so I can identify exactly where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can advice for you is to use [@Nullable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html) and [@NonNull](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html) annotations for all methods with return values. It would not help you to get line where null pointer is but would help to prevent such situations in future.

So if method may return `null` and you have it in call sequence you will get warning from Android Studio about this. In this case it is better to break sequence and check for `null`.

For example:

```
private static class Seq {

    private final Random rand = new Random();

    @NonNull
    public Seq nonNull() {
        return new Seq();
    }

    @Nullable
    public Seq nullable() {
        return rand.nextInt() % 100 > 50 ? new Seq() : null;
    }

}
```

If you write `new Seq().nonNull().nonNull().nullable().nonNull();` you will get warning from IDE:

```
Method invocation `new Seq().nonNull().nonNull().nullable().nonNull()` may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

The best solution in this case is to change code like so:

```
    Seq seq = new Seq().nonNull().nonNull().nullable();
    if (seq != null) {
        seq.nonNull();
    }
```

**Don't forget to add it into Gradle build script**

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.+'
```

Comment: I like the idea of this. But I don't think I can apply it in my application. Might use it in the future though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive on the way you are doing it. This makes your code tightly coupled and not unit testable.

```
var.getSomething().getSomethingElse().setNewValue(stuff.getValue().getWhatever());
```

Instead do something like

```
var.getSomething();
```

that get something internally does whatever you are doing as a part of

```
getSomethingElse().setNewValue(stuff.getValue().getWhatever())
```

In the same way `getSomethingElse()` should perform whatever you are doing as a part of

```
setNewValue(stuff.getValue().getWhatever())
```