# My application crashes when opening. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

My application in Android Studio is crashing. The app is for wasting time. I've added a button for switching layout and this happens. Here is the code:

```
package com.doggoplayer.appperditempo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView texto =  (findViewById(R.id.textView));
        Button bottonemerdoso = (findViewById(R.id.button));
        Button bottone =  findViewById(R.id.bottone);
        TextView nodissing = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button mammt = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        bottonemerdoso.setOnClickListener(v -> setContentView(R.layout.layoutlvl2));

        bottone.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            texto.getVisibility();
            texto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        });

        mammt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            nodissing.getVisibility();
            nodissing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
    }}
```

Here is the stacktrace from logcat:

```
2020-11-26 10:11:15.625 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo-1/lib/arm
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.722 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.795 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.doggoplayer.appperditempo.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:15)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6729)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2652)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2766)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1507)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6243)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.796 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:891)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:781)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.doggoplayer.appperditempo.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:15)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6729)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2652)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2766)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1507)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6243)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:891)
    2020-11-26 10:11:15.797 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:781)
    2020-11-26 10:11:16.456 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    2020-11-26 10:11:16.458 5785-5785/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.doggoplayer.appperditempo, PID: 5785
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doggoplayer.appperditempo/com.doggoplayer.appperditempo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6243)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.doggoplayer.appperditempo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6729)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2652)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6243) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android NullPointerException - Debugging a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470034/android-nullpointerexception-debugging-a-specific-line)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar issue when turning my phone (changing from portrait to landscape re-started the activity). Your button seems to change to layoutlvl2, but when you start again, you keep activity_main. Maybe this is issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the code is that all three buttons are on the `activity_main`. Now since one button press changed the layout, the other two button views are lost now. In `onClickListener` there is View object "v", which is now null because the layout has changed. That is the reason the onclick method is giving a nullPointerException.
If you want to show a different layout or activity you should try using intents. That is much safer and reliable.

The code for using intents to change activity is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: in the activity_main are present only two buttons. One for wasting time and one for changing layout

Comment: Yeah so maybe that other button is creating problem.

Comment: Remove that button code and try. And yeah tell me if it works. Even I'm curious.

Comment: Yes. If i remove that code it works because in the previous version of the app, which has only one activity, the app works.

Comment: if you want all the versions of my app tell me :)))

Comment: So yeah use intents if you want show some other screen on a button press. That is safer.

Comment: can you tell me how use intents for changing activity? thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can see the code for using intents.

Comment: Sorry if i ask but i'm 13 and i'm not very expert with java. Where i need to insert the intent for changing activity with a button?

Comment: Inside the `setOnClick` method for the button where you are changing the layout, instead of `setContentView();`

Comment: First, create an activity. Write the second layout code in the xml file of that activity and then in place of `ActivityName.class` write the name of the java file of that activity. Suppose the java file is named SecondActivity.java, then in the intent, you will use `Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);`

Comment: And if you still don't understand then you should learn the basics first. They are documented very well by google. This is the link to it. It is a series of articles. You will learn more and more just read and then click next for further steps.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project